# How to configure RAID 1 from Recovery Mode?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, raid, raid1

I have a server is composed from two HDD 1500 GB SATA (/dev/sda and /dev/sdb), one of this have failed and server is in recovery mode. I want to fix it, first I made a backup of the important information. Then I changed the hard disk that failed.

I don't know how to start. I need to know how to repair and copy the information from one disk to other, and how to configure RAID 1 in Ubuntu 12.04 if it is in Recovery Mode.

Here is how my system is set up:

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       3.8G  319M  3.5G   9% /
none            3.7G  4.0K  3.7G   1% /dev
none            774M  264K  774M   1% /var/run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /var/run/lock
none            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /var/run/shm

# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders, total 2930277168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000dd8e4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders, total 2930277168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid10] 
unused devices: <none>

# mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md/0
# mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md/1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to be in recovery mode for this; you can just boot the system normally.  Then partition the new disk just like the old one was and add any partitions on the new disk to any existing arrays with something like:

```
sudo mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1
```

After that if you check the status of the array with `sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0` you should see that it is resyncing.

Also 12.04 is deprecated and reaches end of life next year so you should upgrade to 14.04.